vscode ced-1-TextEditorDecorationType9-1 style How to customize
I am using this color theme, and the text color in the comments below looks very poor in this color theme. How can I customize this color?
I have looked through the documentation and used Google, but I cannot find anything related to this.
effect of display
I currently know that this effect is related to this class, and I have looked through the documentation and Googled it, but I haven't found the results I was looking for.
enterStyle correlation

This question is similar to: Customize colors in VS Code?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I wanted to edit the color of this particular comment text, but I couldn't find a configuration for it.
